# How to add a self sizing child viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Suppose there is a child view controller containing a self sizing label with fixed margins on top left right and bottom.

[image]

How could I add that to the parent view controller in such a way that the
topmost view of the child view controller has sufficient size to accomodate the label?

The width of the view must be equal to that of the host view
the height needs to vary.

numlines is 0 (obviously).

Comment: You may want to provide some more information. Maybe it would be great for you to use a presentation controller to create you own alert controller. I've done this many times and could provide more details if you want. Otherwise I can only guess - use autolayout - so you never have to set frames.

Comment: Yes, I would like to see your sample code for a custom alert controller. I need to stash mine under the navbar.

Comment: As for autlayout: i;m using it with 4 fixed constraint on label left right top and bottom, the uilabel is 0 lines so in the absence of autlayout I would've just called sizetofit on it then derived the height of the topmost view from that given that margins are known. Maybe I should turn off autolayout cause in this case it casuses more problems then it solves. But I was cutious how to solve this with autolayout just for kicks. Even though it seems to be not the right tool for this particular job.

Comment: I will provide some starting points for you later this day - right now I'm busy.

Comment: Hm, I think I still don't get how you actually want to position your label. Maybe you can add an example image to your question. And is it just a label? Or are you trying to create a alert view like popup?

Comment: alertviewlikepopup. there is a button to the left and a button to the right of the label. But they are fixed. as is the label width. I want the child view controller height to change to accomodate the label + the margins.

Comment: Added an answer. Would be good to get some feedback...

Comment: I guess I was very clumsy explaining what I need: I need the sizing part of the equation, not the presentation candy part of it.

Comment: basically a self sizing child view controller that is large enough to fit the label.

Comment: If you only need help in layouting and setting up your constraints - provide what you already have so we have a base to discuss on...

Comment: what I have is a label pinned with a fixed margin to the top, bottom of the child view controller top most view. It's also pinned on the left to one button and on the right to another button. Now I want the height of UILabel required to display the current uilabel content to drive the height of the topmost view of the child view controller (that is for it to be the lablel size plus the margins). Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess I'll kill autolayout. Thanks.

Comment: ? Why killing it? For having an adaptive layout you should always use layout constraints. The problem is: Provide code. Provide screenshots - layout issues are hard to get from words. If you expect to have helpful answers you have to provide more details. It's not that hard to put code in here or to upload screenshots from interface builder. But I think I got your problem and will try to help you as soon as I have time for a small example project.

Comment: attached an image. Finally learned how to do that here ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115178/discussion-between-anton-tropashko-and-orschaef).

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to build a custom "alert view popup" I suggest to use `UIPresentationController`.

With that you can present your alert modally via `presentViewController:animated:` and customize the presentation animation.
It's the best approach if you want to use your custom alert in several view controllers later - just present the controller.

Have a look at this Tutorial (it's not the best out there regarding presentation controllers in general, but it mostly fits your goal):

http://dativestudios.com/blog/2014/06/29/presentation-controllers/

The controller you present (your alert) should layout the label and buttons dynamically with autolayout - and the target frame for the whole view controller is set via `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView`.

Get into the topic and try it out - no one here will provide you a full implementation. If you are stuck at any specific problem then come back and we try to solve it together ;)

Cheers
Orlando